# Return response from Express server using JSON API spec

Tags: javascript, express, json-api

I've set up a basic app to experiment with RBAC, Express servers and API design. I have setup various API routes that currently return the response I get from the db as JSON. e.g. This is a route that returns a user, their user details and all the apples they own (apples are my fictitious resource).

```
  userProfile: async (req, res) => {
    const isLoggedIn = req.isAuthenticated();

    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      return res.status(401).end('Unauthorized');
    };

    const userId = req.params.id;
    const isAdmin = hasRole(req, 'admin');

    if (!isAdmin && !isUser(req, parseInt(userId))) {
      return res.status(401).end('Unauthorized');
    };

    const results = await db.users.getUserProfile(userId);
    res.status(200).json(results.rows);
  }
```

And I get a response at the moment that looks like this:

```
[{
  "user_id": 2,
  "user_name": "ben",
  "user_role": "user",
  "apple_id": 12,
  "apple_name": "another apple"
},
{
  "user_id": 2,
  "user_name": "ben",
  "user_role": "user",
  "apple_id": 6,
  "apple_name": "Granny Smith"
}]
```

Fine, no probs. Now I want to model the response to make sure it adheres to the [JSON API spec](https://jsonapi.org/)

Where/how should I do this? Is there some middleware I should be using? Or should I create some factory or something that takes the response and models it as required?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can create a service which parse JSON data and outputs the result as expected. You can do mapping of the objects..

Comment: Just create a Utility function to wrap your JSON into the required response.

Comment: There are a lot of existing JavaScript and TypeScript implementations that helps you with serialization: https://jsonapi.org/implementations/#client-libraries-javascript